# How to create a external menu link in drupal 8?

Tags: symfony, menuitem, drupal-8

I want to create an external menu link here is my code.

```
class MyClass extends DeriverBase implements ContainerDeriverInterface {
    public function getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition) {
    $links = [];

    $sites = [
        'www.google.com' => 'http://gwa-caromaww2.netsol.local/',
        'www.drupal.org' => 'http://drupal.org/'
    ];

    foreach ($sites as $key => $site) {
      $links['sites'.$key] = [
        'title' => $key,
        'path' => $site,
      ] + $base_plugin_definition;
    }

    return $links;
  }
}
```

When I installed my custom module It genrates an error saying:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 190 of D:\workspace\projects\caromaww\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider.php).

Comment: Drupal 8 allows you to create external menu links out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing:

```
 'url' => $site
```

instead of path.

External pointing menu links would use an url value
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/menu-api/providing-module-defined-menu-links